# SCADA devices and VPN device

Tags: vpn

I have several SCADA systems that are all static IP addressed system running on my network.  I would like to out a small VPN Device (for lack of a better word) between the device and my network.  The device will basically connect to a VPN system (sonicwall so far).  The device should simply take the IP packets, and wrap them in a VPN wrapper and shoot it off on the network.

Does anyone know of such a small device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product recommendations are not on topic here, but I think all you want to do is layer 2 bridging.  You could implement L2TP over a VPN link fairly easily.

It depends on your goal, though.  If you're looking merely to implement an RTU-type thing with the SCADA system, you could use a routed VPN; if the devices use the VPN router as their gateway, your goal will be accomplished.

If you want to bridge that network with another network over a VPN, layer 2 bridging is the way to go.